# Flowchart - Python

Tags: python, while-loop, flowchart

I need to write a program for the given flowchart

[image]

My code:

```
x,y,d=list(map(int,input().split()))
temp=0

while x<=y:
    
    x=temp
    
    while temp>0:
        
        if temp%10==d:
            
            print(x)
            x+=1
            
        else:
            
            temp//=10
            
        x+=1
```

Input:

8 30 9

Output:

9 19 29

My output:

SoftTimeLimitExceeded()

Can I know where I did the mistake in my program?

Comment: y doesn't change anywhere in the flowchart, so why/how should it change form 30 to 19?

Answer (score 0):

1. "Assign x to temp" should be `temp=x`, not `x=temp`
2. Look at the first three lines of your loop:
   your starting variables are

   ```
    x=8
    y=30
    d=9
    temp=0

    while x<=y: # this is true on the first loop, since 8 < 30

        x=temp # now both x and temp are 0

        while temp>0: # temp is 0, so the inside of this loop never runs
   ```

So the only thing your code does is infinitely executing `x=temp`

Try to incorporate my first remark, and set temp to something other than 0.

Comment: but still it's not working